# Can a bald person be a Nazir?

Tags: halacha, nozir, haircuts

We know someone who takes a Nazirite vow upon themselves must refrain from haircuts, wine and coming close to dead bodies, and at the conclusion of their Nazirite period must cut their hair.

What would be the law regarding a person who is naturally completely bald and can't shave any hair at the end?

Can such a person become a Nazir? If so, wouldn't this be a lack in their ability to fulfill this mitzvah?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97402/discussion-on-question-by-alicht-can-a-bald-person-be-a-nazir).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Rambam, Hilchos Nezirus 8:5](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/983592/jewish/Nezirut-Chapter-8.htm#v5):

> נזיר ממורט אינו צריך להעביר תער ואע"פ שאין לו שער או שאין לו כפים הרי זה מקריב קרבנותיו וישתה ויטמא ואם הביא קרבנותיו ולא גלח ראשו אין התגלחת מעכבת
>
> A bald nazirite does not have to pass a razor over his head. Even though [a nazirite] does not have hair or does not have a palm, he may still bring his sacrifices. He [may] then drink [wine] and become impure. If he brought his sacrifices, but did not shave his head, [the failure] to shave does not prevent [the termination of his nazirite vow].

So yes, he can be a nazir, and he just skips the shaving at the end. (Although Radvaz there argues that the correct wording in the Rambam should be that he *does* need to pass a razor over his head, even though there's no hair to remove.)

Comment: The Rambam and Radvaz take the two sides of the dispute in the gemara in [Nazir 46b](https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.46b?lang=bi). Beit Hillel says he must pass the razor